# How dependent is Paper Jam on Amiibo?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

I don't have a New 3DS or the NFC Reader thing, so I don't have any Amiibo, and I have no plans to get any. I know that Paper Jam can use Amiibo to create Character Cards that you can use in battle.

Is the fact that I don't have and don't plan to get any Amiibo for this game (or any other) going to limit my ability to progress in this game? Or is everything possible without the Amiibo, just more difficult without them?

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to inhibit progression at all. They're free actions you can do in combat and they vary from buffs to free damage, but it's nothing you can't do yourself. It's not that much more difficult to not use them, so they're essentially a "nice to have."

As an added perk, if any cards (normally used with amiibo) drop in the game, you can sell them for extra coins.